# adb shell settings put secure sysui_nav_bar commands on Android Oreo 8.0 not works without root

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm trying to use this "set of commands" on Android Oreo but i have some issue. For testing i'm using this command on my Nexus 5x:

```
adb shell settings put secure sysui_nav_bar "space,recent;home;back,space"
```

So i decided to implement this command inside my app and try without root help. In the app manifest i added the permission to write secure settings:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Then in my MainActivity i added a button to run the command that you read before.

```
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("settings put secure sysui_nav_bar \"space,recent;home;back,space\""); 
            } catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        }
    });
```

Once my app was built i ran it on my 5x and via adb i typed this command to allow to write secure settings:`adb shell pm grant com.customizer.smart.batterysavercustomizer android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` and this command was excuted without errors. But when i try to tap on my "testButton" nothing happened and 0 erorrs inside androidmonitor.

Last try that i did was with root help. I edited my preview command button:

```
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c settings put secure sysui_nav_bar \"space,recent;home;back,space\""); 
        } catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    }
});
```

When i tapped on my testButton the app asked to garant root permission, and it works. But how is possible that on the same phone the app "Custom navigation bar" app that uses the same adb command works without root ?.
I followed this: [guide on XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-change-your-nav-bar-icons-or-re-arrange-the-buttons-without-root/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Settings class instead of Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

```
testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Settings.Secure.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "sysui_nav_bar", valueToSave);
        } else {
            //Write secure Settings permission not granted
            //Show instructions about how to grant it via ADB
        }
    }
});
```